# C# - Ping results don't work when page is refreshed

Tags: c#, dns, ping, ttl

I have the following C# code to get the IP address of a given domain (because I need to validate the DNS information).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string domain = "www.stackoverflow.com";                            

    try
    {
            IPAddress address = null;                                    
            address = Dns.GetHostEntry(domain).AddressList[0]; //get the host IP from the name provided
            PingResult.InnerHtml += domain + " - " + address ;
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
            //some DNS error happened, return the message
        PingResult.InnerHtml += domain + " - " + string.Format("DNS Error: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I get the IP just fine (www.stackoverflow.com - 198.252.206.16) when I first load the page but then if I have the page opened and if there is anything changed in the DNS and I refresh the page I get the same old (cached?) results.

What to do to avoid having to close my browser and opening my browser every time? How can I also get the TTL value set in the DNS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is this PingResult

Comment: address has the same IP address with different domains?

Comment: PingResult is just a textbox. the IP address changes with different domains but once the info is retrieve it is cached? so if there are any changes made in the DNS it will not show until the browser is closed and opened again.